# Pyspark: pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a spark dataframe to a bigquery table. This was working, but now I call a pandas udf before writing the data to bigquery. For some reason, when I call the pandas udf before writing the spark dataframe to bigquery I now see the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 287, in dump_stream
    batch = _create_batch(series, self._timezone)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 256, in _create_batch
    arrs = [create_array(s, t) for s, t in series]
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    arrs = [create_array(s, t) for s, t in series]
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1579619644892_0001/container_1579619644892_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 240, in create_array
    return pa.Array.from_pandas(s, mask=mask).cast(t, safe=False)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 474, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 169, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 69, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Which, from the executor logs below, looks like its being caused by an incorrect parquet schema where the timestamp columns are being inferred as integers?

```
20/01/20 22:45:38 INFO ParquetWriteSupport: Initialized Parquet WriteSupport with Catalyst schema:
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "firstname",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "status",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "entry_date",
    "type" : "timestamp",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "last_status_date",
    "type" : "timestamp",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
and corresponding Parquet message type:
message spark_schema {
  optional binary id (UTF8);
  optional binary firstname (UTF8);
  optional binary status (UTF8);
  optional int96 entry_date;
  optional int96 last_status_date;
}
```

This is confusing because this does not happen when I run my code without applying the pandas_udf. The udf is not manipulating the date columns in any way...

```
def main():
    # apply pandas udf 
    df.groupBy('firstname').apply(my_pandas_udf)

    # drop some columns
    cols_to_drop = ['firstname']

    # save to bigquery
    df \
        .drop(*cols_to_drop) \
        .write \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "<TEMP_BUCKET_NAME>") \
        .option("project", "PROJECT_ID") \
        .option("credentialsFile","/path/to/my/credentials.json") \
        .option("parentProject", "PROJECT_ID") \
        .option("table", "PROJECT_ID:dataset.table") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save()

def udf_schema():
    return StructType([
        StructField('id', StringType(), True),
        StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
        StructField('status', StringType(), True),
        StructField('entry_date', TimestampType(), True),
        StructField('last_status_date', TimestampType(), True),
    ])

@pandas_udf(udf_schema(), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_pandas_udf(df):
    df = df.sort_values('entry_date', ascending=False)
    oldest_date = df['entry_date'].iloc[0]
    df = df[df['entry_date'] >= oldest_date]
    df = df.copy()
    return df
```

What am I doing wrong? This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893582/pyarrow-lib-arrowtypeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-str) seems to have a similar issue but as of 1/21/2020 has not been answered.

**Edit (1): Dataframe datatypes before & after pandas_udf**
The error occurs when returning from the pandas_udf, but here are the datatypes for the spark dataframe before its passed to the pandas_udf

```
==> BEFORE 

id string
firstname string
status string
entry_date timestamp
date_status_change timestamp
last_status_date timestamp
```

Comment: Can you please print the dataframe schema before and after running  my_pandas_udf() ?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz Added, in **Edit (1)**. The error is occurring when pyarrow attempts to convert the pandas df back to a spark df upon returning from `my_pandas_udf`, so I was only able to print the datatypes before the udf call.

Comment: Even stranger is that this works fine with a smaller subset of data locally, but when I run on AWS EMR with 10,000+ rows I see this error?

Comment: Usually if things are working locally but not in distributed manner, it means that there's a serialization issue involved.

Comment: Did you figure out anything? I'm running into the same issue on AWS Glue... the weird thing is that it was working fine and I just ran into this issue today for the first time.

Comment: @aiguofer Apologies, I don't think I ever directly solved this issue. I think I ended up creating a separate python script that saves a dataframe to s3, then updates my bigquery table. And then a second script that actually pulls data from bigquery, and sent that dataframe to a pandas_udf. I havent had any issues with this so far. I'm using the `from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer` => full code here: https://pastiebin.com/5ed178fdeffa2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem recently, and I believe the error occurs due to pandas casting every column to `object` when reading from spark.

The way I fixed my issue was to explicitly cast the timestamp columns after the pandas dataframe was created. So in your case, something like:

```
@pandas_udf(udf_schema(), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_pandas_udf(df):
    df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'])
    df['last_status_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_status_date'])
    df = df.sort_values('entry_date', ascending=False)
    oldest_date = df['entry_date'].iloc[0]
    df = df[df['entry_date'] >= oldest_date]
    df = df.copy()
    return df
```

Comment: You may also need to set any `pd.NaT` to an actual date.