# python pandas writing parquet file I just read: Conversion failed for column

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_parquet("/Users/myuser/Downloads/input.parquet")
file.to_parquet("/Users/hazout/mysuer/output.parquet")
```

I am trying to read and write a parquet file (I plan to modify it too, but first things first).

I get `pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column gtis_per_league with type object')`

I have 46 columns, do I really have to redefine and massage each column even when I don't touch them?

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845208/pyspark-pyarrow-lib-arrowtypeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-timestamp

Comment: It looks like column `gtis_per_league` has got a mix of string and int. Parquet expect consistent types within each column. If your data isn't a good shape it will require some massaging indeed.